# How Do I Get Testers for my App Submissions?

Tags: applications, ios-appstore, xcode, mac-appstore

I submitted my enrollment in the Apple Developer Program a couple of days ago. I'm waiting to be approved.

I have Mac 3D Puzzle apps that were created as .app files using Unity 5.3.2. I plan to create iPad versions from Unity which create Xcode projects. I would like to take advantage of the **TestFlight Beta Testing** program for this app but I don't know anyone to invite. Many of the people I know are iPhone/iPad users but are not technically inclined where I would invite them to test my apps. Can I use this program?

Comment: Is your question how to get testers for your program or if you can use this program?

Comment: I was trying to ask two questions. (1) Can I use the TestFlight Beta Testing program for apps not created using Xcode? and (2) How do I get testers in general using the TestFlight Beta Testing program? Sorry what I wrote was not clear.

Comment: That's okay :P Our rules don't allow multiple questions per question. Please move your 2nd question to a new question.

Comment: Okay I will edit this and create a new question.

Comment: I just updated this and created a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Most people, myself included, ask family, friends, and co-workers to help test. Depending on the technical details of what you want tested, you can also put out calls for testers on Twitter and Facebook.

There are also websites that will help find testers for you, especially for games. [Toucharcade](http://Toucharcade.com) is a good site for finding game testers.

Comment: Also, **reddit** has a specific [subreddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/AlphaAndBetaUsers) in which you can ask for testers.

Comment: So it appears that Apple does not have a staff of app testers other than the TestFlight Beta Testing program. I plan to sell these apps and I'm concerned about just throwing my apps out there to people I don't know. I have a few people that have already tested it. I guess I thought it was a more formal process like Amazon and Microsoft appears to have. My puzzles are not that complicated that I need a huge group of testing done. Thanks everyone!